# C#から自作のC++DLLのクラスを呼び出す方法

Tags: c#, unity3d, c++, pinvoke

UnityC#にて重たい処理をDLLにやってもらおうと思い、
ViusalStudioを用いてC++のDLLを[こちらを参考に](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged)作成しました。

メソッドを呼び出すことはできたので、
今度はクラス経由で呼び出してみようと思い
C++側のクラスの定義をMSDNの[ここ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/81h27t8c.aspx)を参考にクラスを作成したのですが
C#側からどのように呼び出せばいいのかがわかりません。

---

C#側

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Must Need DLL Import 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CallDlls : MonoBehaviour {

    // From c++ Dll (unmanaged)
    [DllImport("MathFuncsDll")]
    public static extern float TestMultiply(float a, float b);

    // From c++ Dll (unmanaged)
    [DllImport("MathFuncsDll")]
    public static extern float TestDivide(float a, float b);

    public float multiply(float a,float b)
    {
        return TestMultiply(a, b);
    }
}
```

---

C++DLL側

**// MathFuncsDll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
float TestMultiply(float a, float b)
{
    return a * b;
}

float TestDivide(float a, float b)
{
    if (b == 0) {
        return 0;
        //throw invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
    }

    return a / b;
    }
}
```

**// MathFuncsDll.h**

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

extern "C" {
    class MATHFUNCSDLL_API TestClass {
        float TestMultiply(float a, float b);
        float TestDivide(float a, float b);
        //MATHFUNCSDLL_API float TestMultiply(float a, float b);
        //MATHFUNCSDLL_API float TestDivide(float a, float b);
    };
}
```

Comment: managed C++ は試されたのでしょうか？

Comment: まだ試してないです。クラスライブラリを試してみようかと思ってますが、そもそも私のやろうとしてる事が非推奨のようなので、c#側でマネージャーを持ってc++側のメソッド呼び出しを管理するような仕組みにしようと思ってます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

技術的にはC#コードから直接C++クラスのメンバ関数を呼ぶことも可能です。ただし、幾つかの理由からお薦めできません。@時計屋さん回答にある解決策を採用したほうがよいと思います。

DLL/C++クラスのメンバ関数はthiscall呼出し規約(calling convention)をもちますので、`DllImport`属性で[`CallingConvention.ThisCall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx)を指定し、`EntryPoint`には"マングリングされた関数名"を指定する必要があります。詳細は記事 [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class) が参考になります。

お薦めできない理由：

- DLL/C++側クラスのコンストラクタ/デストラクタを、C#側から直呼び出すことはできません。少なくともC++クラスオブジェクトの`new`/`delete`操作を行うC++側にヘルパー関数が必要です。
- DLL/C++側でエクスポートされる"マングリングされた関数名"に、C#側では常に追従させる必要があるためメンテナンスコストが高くなります。

Comment: 当該クラスに対するポインタを取得した上で、マングリングされたメソッドをThisCallで呼べば確かに意は通りますし、呼び出しに対する曖昧性も環境依存も無く呼び出しは完結できますね。
全くその点、思慮に無かったので、非常に参考になり、又自分の不勉強を恥じる次第です。
ご教授いただき本当に有り難うございました。

Comment: マングリング自体がわかってなかったので調査したところメソッドのオーバーロードやネームスペースの関係でシンボル名が変化するんですね。
教えていただいたページも拝見しました、CallingConvention.ThisCallを使用するには常にマングリングされたシンボル名が必要で、メソッドを作成するたびに、それが必要になるような気がします　なのでメンテナンスコストが高いという事ですね。　C++側をクラスにするのはやめてC#でマネージャークラスを作成しC++側はメソッドだけにして制御しようと思います。

Answer (score 9):

DllImport属性を使うことで、ネイティブコードを呼び出すことはできますが、
C++で作成したクラスをDllImport属性を使って、.NET Frameworkで利用することはできません。

解決策としては、

1. 関数ベースのインターフェースを別途用意して、管理する
2. C++/CLI等を利用してラッパーを作成する

等が考えられると思います。

Answer (score 5):

一般的には時計屋さんの回答にあるように関数ベースでの呼び出しが使われます。

難易度は上がりますが、他の方が紹介されていない方法としてCOMインターフェースがあります。
まじめにレジストリ登録しなくても、C++にてCOMインターフェースに沿ったC++クラスを実装しそのポインターを返します。C#側ではCOMインターフェースに相当するC#インターフェースを定義し、[Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown(v=vs.110).aspx)などでインスタンスを得ます。
この方法であればyohjpさんの提案に近い状態ですが、マングル名を意識する必要はなくなります。

Comment: COMを使うことで､確かに相互運用可能ですね。レジストリに登録が必須だと思っていたのですが、当該メソッド経由でディスパッチも軽くできますし。
何を作るかにもよりますけど、ATLあたりを使えば相応に楽できるかな？と回答を拝見して思いました。

Comment: まずCOM自身を勉強するところから始める必要がありそうです。　COMインターフェースに沿ったC++クラスの実装方法を調査しないとなんともわかりません。後はUnityで実装して動作すれば使ってみたいなあと思います。マングリングした名前を意識しなくていいのは正直良いですね。

Comment: COMインタフェースにするなら、もう少しコードを短くできます。DllImportで戻り値の型にインタフェース型を指定すれば良いです。そのインタフェースの定義に[InterfaceType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.interfacetypeattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)属性やGuid属性を指定しておけば大丈夫です。```Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown```が不要になります。

Comment: @Egtra はい自分で書くときは戻り値にインターフェース型を指定します。ただしこれはわかっている人がやる方法であり、説明し辛かったのであえてメソッドを紹介しました。（蛇足的な回答ですし、Unityでdllという時点で質問者さんの勘違いが予見されていましたし。）

Answer (score 1):

Unityの事は全く知らないのでC++/CLIを使って良い環境かどうかはわかりませんが、C++/CLIを使った.NETとネイティブC++の連携なら以下の記事が参考になると思います。

- [[連載! とことん VC++] 第 9 回 C++/CLI を利用した相互運用 ～.NET からのネイティブ C++ 資産の再利用～](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VisualC-a1dc1f1d/)
- [[C++] C++/CLI を用いて、.NET 対応アプリケーションから MFC 対応クラスを使用する](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VisualC-howto-76f9cd9e)

逆方向（ネイティブC++ → .NET）の記事もあります。

- [[連載! とことん VC++] 第 8 回 C++/CLI を利用した相互運用 ～ネイティブ C++ から .NET の利用～](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VisualC-ee06b200/)

なお、.NETとネイティブC++間でオブジェクトをやり取りする場合は一部を除いて変換しないといけないので、やりたい事によってはオーバーヘッドが大きくなり効果的でないかもしれません。
また、C++/CLIの参考書・記事は少なく、.NETとネイティブC++に精通していないと学習するのが難しと思います。

Comment: 確かにあまりヒットする記事を見つけられないのと、技術レベルが高くて苦戦しています。　やりたい事は山ほどありまして、以降の事をすべてC++のスレッドで行うというものです。●リソースのダウンロード、●Tarの展開、●Zip解凍、●解凍したUnityリソースをロードしてファイル保存、●ファイルシステムの構築、等になります。　UnityC#で行ったところヒープ領域が膨大になり、アプリに実装した時にメモリが不足する可能性があるためC++へ移行しようとしています。　ページ教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

C++のクラスをC#でDLLを経由して呼び出すことはできません。
そういう場合は、C++/CLIでラッピングする必要があります。

```
class TestClass {
public:
    float TestMultiply(float a, float b);
    float TestDivide(float a, float b);
};
```

として定義した場合は、C++/CLIで以下のように書くことができます。

```
public ref class TestClassWrapper {
internal:
    TestClass* Native;
public:
    TestClassWrapper() { Native = new TestClass(); } //非マネージクラスのインスタンスを生成
    ~TestClassWrapper(){ this->!TestClassWrapper(); } // ファイナライザを呼ぶ
    !TestClassWrapper(){ delete native; }  // ファイナライザでは非マネージクラスのインスタンスを削除
    float Multiply(float a, float b){ return Native->TestMultiply(a, b); }
    float Diviede(float a, float b){ return Native->TestDivide(a, b); }
};
```

コンストラクタで非マネージクラスのオブジェクトを生成し、ファイナライザでそのオブジェクトを削除、デストラクタではそのままファイナライザを呼び出します。
あとはメソッドをC++のメンバー関数を呼べばいいですね。

C#やVBからは以下のように使うことができます。

```
using(var calc = new TestClassWrapper()) {
    var ret1 = calc.Multiply(5.5f, 5.5f); 
    var ret2 = calc.Diviede(10.0f, 2.0f);
    Console.WriteLine(ret1 + ":" + ret2);
}
```

---

2019年1月29日 - "{"が抜けていたので修正しました。

---